# PHP for loop with one of the tags different for each item

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP script. This is a image gallery and I'd like to add a description for each image in the "p" tag. What is the best way to do this?

```
    <?php
     for($i=1;$i<=35;$i++)
     {
        echo
        '<a href="images/gallery/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
        '<img src="images/thumb/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
        '<p></p>'.
        '</a>';
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: `'<p>DESCRIPTION HERE</p>"`?

Comment: I would suggest inserting the names and descriptions into a table in a database. That way you can query the database and pull the corresponding description for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did some research here's what I found. It works. So if anyone needs the code:

```
     $title = array("title1", "title2", "title3", "title4" ... "title35");
     for($i=1;$i<=35;$i++)
     {
        echo
        '<div class="thumb">'.
        '<a href="images/gallery/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
        '<img src="images/thumb/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
        '<p>'.$title[$i].'</p>'.
        '</a>'.
        '</div>';
      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The files in your sample code are titled `1.jpg` to `35.jpg`.

Create another array with 35 descriptions and access it in your `for` loop with `$i`.

Comment: How should I do this? Sorry I'm new to PHP.

Comment: @MarkShark Do your research and give it a try. If you get stuck come back and let us know specifically what you're having issues with and we'll help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$i` is the filename as your code suggests, you could add the filename as the description like this:

```
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=35;$i++)
 {
    echo
    '<a href="images/gallery/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
    '<img src="images/thumb/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
    '<p>Filename: '.$i.'</p>'.
    '</a>';
 }
?>
```